# Breeding with Power Belt

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I am playing Pokemon Omega Ruby. I want to breed a pokemon with 5 IVs, so I bought a Power Belt from the battle resort. 
I've read many websites that said Power Belt will pass the Defense IV from holder parent to child, but when I give a Power Belt to a Snorunt with perfect HP and Defense then breed it with another Snorunt which holds a Destiny Knot and has perfect SpAtk, SpDef and Speed, I don't get any children with perfect Defense; instead, the child from these parents always have perfect SpDef!

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using *Power Belt* and not a *Power Band*? Because that item passes SpDef IV down. Or maybe you gave *Power Band* to the wrong parent.

Comment: I'm sure Power Belt passes down Defense IVs and Power Band passes down Special Defense IVs.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanations are that the item you've purchased and using is the Power Belt and not the Power Band, or that you've given the Power Band to the wrong Pokemon.

The way Power items and the Destiny Knot interact are as follows:

- The Destiny Knot requires five random IVs from both the Mother and Father Pokemon to be passed down.
- When a Pokemon holds a Power item, the related stat from the Pokemon holding it is guaranteed to be passed down. This counts against the 5 IVs for Destiny Knot.
- As such, if you are using the Power Band, the Defence IV of the Pokemon holding it is guaranteed to be passed down, along with 4 other random IVs (excluding Defence) from either parent.